# Why are magnetic field lines perpendicular to the surface of a ferromagnetic material?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

It is known that magnetic field lines become nearly perpendicular to the surface of a ferromagnetic material. The quantitative proof which uses the boundary condition requires that magnetization at the surface be zero.

**Question:** *Why is magnetization at the surface of a ferromagnetic material zero? Also, can someone give a qualitative explanation for the approaching perpendicularness of magnetic field lines and the surface of a ferromagnetic material?*

Comment: Probably missing something, so I'll comment rather than answering. Could you outline the argument you've seen that requires zero magnetization at the surface? The argument I'm familiar with is as follows. Faraday's law says that in the static case when there are no *macroscopic* currents present, the curl of H is zero. This requires the parallel component of H to be continuous across the surface of a permeable material, which means that $B_{\parallel}=\mu H_{\parallel}$ has a discontinuity. This means that whatever the direction of B inside the surface, it has to be small outside the surface.

Comment: Are you specifically interested in ferromagnetism, not just high permeability?

Comment: No, I am interested in high permeability but since I needed a qualitative explanation, I wrote ferromagnetic.

Comment: @BenCrowell So, the discontinuity equation has a $K$, i.e. current! Is that current supposed to be free current only?

Comment: a way of seeing the field  is with iron filings. searched "iron filings magnet photo" and there is no real perpendicularity , so I do not know what you are talking about.for example: http://www.google.gr/imgres?imgurl=http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/visualscience/files/2013/04/Iron-Filing-Experiment.png&imgrefurl=http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/visualscience/2013/04/20/saturn-gets-drenched-by-its-eroding-rings/&h=2048&w=1536&sz=2561&tbnid=BA-3H9uAlTH8oM:&tbnh=89&tbnw=67&zoom=1&usg=__vuhtdgO-leT1YFj9_svcFuG2IWg=&docid=PPnaLacJdWI1vM&sa=X&ei=tiQjUuuCB8HxhQersYHYBg&ved=0CFIQ9QEwDA&dur=5159

Comment: @Cheeku: Again, it would be helpful if you would edit your question to briefly present the argument you're talking about. Otherwise it's not clear, at least to me, what feature of the argument you're asking about.

Comment: Can you please show the quantitative proof too?

Answer (score 1):

They are not.

However, there are relations at the surface between two materials.
$$\vec{H_1}\wedge\vec{n}=\vec{H_2}\wedge\vec{n}$$
This comes from the Ampere's circuital law used on a very flat rectangle whose long edges are on either side of the domains frontier.
If $1$ designates the air and $2$ designates the ferromagnetic material, since $\vec{B}=\mu\vec{H}$, $$\frac{\vec{B_1}\wedge\vec{n}}{\mu_0}=\frac{\vec{B_2}\wedge\vec{n}}{\mu_{iron}}$$ , i.e. :
$$B_{air,t}=\frac{\mu_{0}}{\mu_{iron}}B_{iron,t}$$
Since $\mu_{iron}>>\mu_{0}$, the tangential component of the magnetic flux density in the air is very small.

As a complement, the other relation is $$\vec{B_1}.\vec{n}=\vec{B_2}.\vec{n}$$ (continuity of the normal component of the magnetic flux density) and comes from $div(\vec{B}=0)$.

Comment: If the tangential component of the magnetic flux density in air is very small, while perhaps not *exactly* perpendicular, would this not be close enough to being so that there's no practical difference?

Answer (score 0):

As is well known divB is always null, and when there are not free currents curlH is also zero. Therefore both the normal components of B and the tangential components of H are continuous at the boundary of the sample. This allows us drawing a figure of the lines of force of H and B, showing the so-called law of the refraction of the magnetic field. This refraction is very pronounced when permeabilities are very different. In your example, if the permeability of the sample is very higher than the surrounding, the magnetic field B in the sample will be intense (field plot dense) and practically parallel to the boundary while outside the field is weak and perpendicular) to the border.